# Dynamics 365 default value in FetchXML

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, fetchxml

Is there anyway I can receive a default value in Fetch XML queries

For example
`<attribute name="fullname" />`

If in the entity "fullname" is not set in dynamics currently it's not returning the attribute. Is there any way I can receive blank in the result set?

I am using
 `EntityCollection collection = svc.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(body.ToString()));`

I don't want to check for the attribute, don't want to hardcode, in the code as it can be any attribute.

Comment: Is this specific to fullname, or does it happen for other attributes as well? I recall fullname behaving differently than other attributes in some cases.

Comment: fullname is just an example, it can be any attribute.

Comment: But is the behavior the same for other attributes as well? also, just to make sure: When you say it is not returned, you mean that if you ask for contact["fullname"] you get an error?

Comment: yes in fetch xml it's the default behaviour as I know. If any attribute is null or lank Fetch XML result doesn't return the attribute. so as per your query contact["fullname"] will be null.

Comment: Being null is not the same as not having been fetched. If the value in CRM is null, then what else would you expect it to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

This is usual and expected behavior. Just we have to check for existence and availability like below:

```
if (entity.Contains("fullname") && entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("fullname") != null)
{

//your logic here

}
```

In your iteration of `EntityCollection` using `foreach`, use the above check for every attribute of its datatype.

Comment: Thanks Arun. But as I said in the question I do not want to hardcode the attributes.

Comment: @DaemonBee ok then without knowing what’s coming and it’s datatype what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to receive the attribute with blank field.

Comment: @DaemonBee it’s by design, so impossible to change that ourselves. after getting that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're setting your ColumnSet to All/true.

You can query all the entity attributes separately from the metadata using the [RetrieveEntityRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveentityrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)
Make sure to set the EntityFilter to Attributes
This will retrieve all attributes from the metadata for said entity type.

Once you have the list of all existing attributes you can loop check if they exist in the returned entities in your collection
if(!entity.contains(att)) => this means the value is null.

Dynamics by default doesn't return the attribute in the collection if its value is null.